# Rosaria does not apply published cmd_vel

Tags: navigation, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a setup with two laptops connected through Wi-Fi. One laptop runs the `roscore` and `joy` node, publishing `geometry_msgs/Twist` messages. The other laptop receives these messages correctly (`rostopic echo /p3dx/cmd_vel` on both laptops returns the same messages).

The RosAria node (renamed p3dx) listens on the `/p3dx/cmd_vel` topic for these messages and receives them. When the angular velocity of z is 0.5 m/s, it says to receive:

```
RosAria: rcv: 1382108077.236526 0.000000 -0.495674
```

And sent correctly:

```
RosAria: sent vels to to aria (time 1382108077.164065): x vel -60.710151 mm/s, y vel 0.000000 mm/s, ang vel -28.647890 deg/s
```

However, when the linear velocity of x is 0.5 m/s, it says to receive:

```
RosAria: rcv: 1382108210.788572 0.000000 -0.034907
```

(The small angular velocity is due to operation of a joystick.) And sent incorrectly:

```
RosAria: sent vels to to aria (time 1382108210.885190): x vel 500.000000 mm/s, y vel 0.000000 mm/s, ang vel -2.053801 deg/s
```

Luckily, the robot remains stationary and doesn't try to move forward at full speed. However, it simply always remains stationary. Reducing the sent linear velocity in the `geometry_msgs/Twist` message did not resolve the issue.

I have no idea where this multiplication comes from, nor how to debug it.

*Edit:* The question was ill-posed. The actual issue is that the linear velocity is not applied to the robot, while the angular velocity is.

*Edit:* RosAria ouput:

```
RosAria: using port: [/dev/ttyS0]
Could not connect to simulator, connecting to robot through serial port /dev/ttyS0.
Syncing 0
Syncing 1
Syncing 2
Connected to robot.
Name: Artesis_4106
Type: Pioneer
Subtype: p3dx-sh
Loaded robot parameters from p3dx-sh.p
Setting TicksMM from ROS Parameter: 1
Setting DriftFactor from ROS Parameter: 0
Setting RevCount from ROS Parameter: 16570
RosAria: publishing new recharge state 0.
RosAria: publishing new motors state 0.
RosAria: publishing new motors state 1.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92301/rosaria-does-not-apply-published-cmd_vel/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2013-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2013-10-18**:
I'm not sure I understand your question.   RosAria accepts cmd_vel Twist messages in m/s, but converts that to mm/s since that's what ARIA and the Pioneer use.   The "RosAria: rcv" Message is just incorrectly printed, I'll fix that.

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-10-18**:
@ReedHedges The main problem is that the robot isn't moving forward, just turning.

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-10-18**:
@ReedHedges true! I only now see the unit in mm/s. So that's the correct speed. Yet, this is not applied to the robot.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2013-10-18**:
Perhaps you have the same problem as http://answers.ros.org/question/91466/how-to-move-pioneer-3-at-with-rosaria/  .   Post what RosAria prints out for Type: and Subtype: when it connects and I'll look up some calibration parameters you may need to set manually (temporarily until RosAria is fixed)

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-10-20**:
It reads as the same problem, but the parameters that were off for him seem to be correct for me. Or I might have checked those at the wrong location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These log messages indicate that it is setting TicksMM to an incorrect value at startup:

```
Setting TicksMM from ROS Parameter: 1
Setting DriftFactor from ROS Parameter: 0
Setting RevCount from ROS Parameter: 16570
```

You can change them on the command line when using `rosrun` or set with [dynamic reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure).

For a P3DX-SH change TicksMM to 128.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2013-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-10-21**:
Thanks, this did the trick indeed.